# Opening new Window in VS C++

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, window

I have programmed a little tool. Now I wanted to make an Info Window. For that I have created a seperate member in my member strip by clicking it I have such a Method like info clicked... What I want to do just now is, if the user click my button it has to open the new windo Info.h which I have also designed and finished...

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
private: System::Void versionToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         Application::Run(gcnew Info()); // Info is the Name of my window

     }
```

Thanks for helping.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application::Run` is the message-dispatch loop, and you don't want to start another one.

Try just `gcnew Info()->Show()`.

Comment: I have solved like this: Info ^obj = gcnew Info(); obj -> Show() ... Mainly it's the same :-) Thanks